# Creating a Range of Time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to group various ranges of time into the following groups

1. MOrning. (6:30am - 10:30am)
2. Mid (10:31am - 1:30pm)
3. Afternoon (1:31pm - 5:30pm)

I have my data set-up as follows

```
Time Bracket
9:00 AM
9:00 AM
9:30 AM
10:00 AM
11:00 AM
11:15 AM
11:15 AM
11:15 AM
11:15 AM
11:15 AM
11:30 AM
11:45 AM
12:15 PM
12:15 PM
12:15 PM
12:45 PM
12:45 PM
1:15 PM
```

How do I make a new grouping?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Make a grouping where? For what purpose? Describe the desired outcome. Post a sample file with the mocked up result. Use a file sharing service for posting a file.

Comment: You will need a helper column that indicates what group it falls into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adjacent column say Column B to reflect the required group name / time bracket using IF & AND functions.

```
=IF(AND(A2>=TIME(6,30,0),A2<=TIME(10,30,59)),"MORNING",IF(AND(A2>=TIME(10,31,0),A2<=TIME(13,30,59)),"MID",IF(AND(A2>=TIME(13,31,0),A2<=TIME(17,30,59)),"AFTERNOON","EVENING")))
```

Note that in above formula  time slot from 5:31 PM up to 6:29 AM shall be simply considered as EVENING. If you want further split, you can add one more nested IF. Once the data & group names are in place you can create a Pivot Table from it and get the simple report Grouped By the time bracket.